# Is there a way to find the require cache key for a module using webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am using require to load a large file that I want to remove from cache when it's done. Without that, each file is staying in memory forever, which I don't want. Running `delete require.cache['path/to/file']` works locally. When I run a production build, that key no longer exists. I believe it's the way webpack bundles everything, but not sure how to confirm. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `require.resolve` to get the canonical path of a module, which npm uses as the cache key.

```
const key = require.resolve('path/to/file')
delete require.cache[key]
```

The [docs for `require.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) say:

> Use the internal require() machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.